# Where Should Elements Go Using MVC Format Using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, organization

This is my first foray into using an MVC construct (CodeIgniter). I'm hoping someone can tell me where the following elements belong. I have them written; I just want to make sure they're placed properly in their respective locations. This is how my application will run:

1. Call a DB and see if we have a user signed up
2. Route to a signup page
3. Route to the main preferences page for existing users
4. Make DB queries for producing a new user
5. Make update queries when users change their preferences

The service being provided is a cron job cycling every 10 minutes, which I still have written outside of CodeIgniter. Is this something I should/could add to the logic somewhere? It pings Twitter, and does stuff with any new tweets. Let me know if I can clarify any part of this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Model
2. Controller
3. Controller
4. Model
5. Model

Rule of thumb: if it involves the database or the state of the application, it belongs in a model.  If it is HTML or presentation logic, it belongs in a view. Controllers handle the rest of the logic, and help link the views and models together.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of other things that come up too:

- Where should I sanitise data? As it comes from the model - in the controller or finally before I view? I do it generally in the view if it's something like `htmlspecialchars()` (though I'm sure others might disagree).

[Wikipedia has a very good article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: I believe that everything related to the data input/output should go in the model. That includes sanitation. Therefore, in the model, before it is passed to the controller.

Comment: There is an exception though - what if you want the data "as is" in some parts, but then when you need to print it to the page, you'll use `htmlspecialchars()` to ensure there are no script elements etc in it.